# I am getting an error with R tidymodels ranger example. How do I resolve this?

Tags: r, tidymodels

Hello I am getting an error in tidymodels ranger.
I've provided a reproducible example below using reprex as suggested.

Can anyone identify what might be the issue here?

Many thanks.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.5.3
library(tidymodels)
#> -- Attaching packages -------------------------------------- tidymodels 0.1.2 --
#> v broom     0.7.5      v recipes   0.1.15
#> v dials     0.0.9      v rsample   0.0.9 
#> v infer     0.5.4      v tune      0.1.3 
#> v modeldata 0.1.0      v workflows 0.2.2 
#> v parsnip   0.1.5      v yardstick 0.0.7
#> Warning: package 'scales' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> -- Conflicts ----------------------------------------- tidymodels_conflicts() --
#> x scales::discard() masks purrr::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()   masks stats::filter()
#> x recipes::fixed()  masks stringr::fixed()
#> x dplyr::lag()      masks stats::lag()
#> x yardstick::spec() masks readr::spec()
#> x recipes::step()   masks stats::step()

# get and clean data
voters <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/juliasilge/supervised-ML-case-studies-course/master/data/voters.csv")
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   .default = col_double(),
#>   turnout16_2016 = col_character()
#> )
#> See spec(...) for full column specifications.
voters_select <- voters %>% 
  mutate(turnout16_2016 = factor(turnout16_2016)) %>% 
  select(-case_identifier)

# recipe
vote_rec <- voters_select %>% 
  recipe(data = ., turnout16_2016 ~ .) 

# rf model spec
rf_spec <- rand_forest() %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

# fit 
rf_fit <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(vote_rec) %>% 
  add_model(rf_spec) %>% 
  fit(data = voters_select)
#> Error in ranger::ranger(x = maybe_data_frame(x), y = y, num.threads = 1, : unused arguments (x = maybe_data_frame(x), y = y)
#> Timing stopped at: 0 0 0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce your error. You need to make sure all the necessary previous objects have been created as well before you fit the model specification.

Below is a reproducible example copied from the article

```r
library(tidymodels)
data(cells, package = "modeldata")

set.seed(123)
cell_split <- initial_split(cells %>% select(-case), 
                            strata = class)

cell_train <- training(cell_split)
cell_test  <- testing(cell_split)

rf_mod <- 
  rand_forest(trees = 1000) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

set.seed(234)
rf_fit <- 
  rf_mod %>% 
  fit(class ~ ., data = cell_train)
rf_fit
#> parsnip model object
#> 
#> Fit time:  2.7s 
#> Ranger result
#> 
#> Call:
#>  ranger::ranger(x = maybe_data_frame(x), y = y, num.trees = ~1000,      num.threads = 1, verbose = FALSE, seed = sample.int(10^5,          1), probability = TRUE) 
#> 
#> Type:                             Probability estimation 
#> Number of trees:                  1000 
#> Sample size:                      1515 
#> Number of independent variables:  56 
#> Mtry:                             7 
#> Target node size:                 10 
#> Variable importance mode:         none 
#> Splitrule:                        gini 
#> OOB prediction error (Brier s.):  0.1218873
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I ran the above code and still get the same error.

Comment: I can run the code above. @Terryb which version of R and tidymodels are you on?

Comment: @StupidWolf thanks. I am on R version 3.5.2 and tidymodels version 0.1.2